# How to insert a XML file into a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How do I insert this into a SQL table?

```
<ITEM id="1" 
    name="Swimmer Head" 
    mesh_name="eq_head_swim" 
    totalpoint="0" 
    type="equip" 
    res_sex="m" 
    res_level="0" 
    slot="head" 
    weight="2" 
    bt_price="0" 
    hp="4" 
    ap="8" 
    maxwt="0" 
    sf="0" 
    fr="0" 
    cr="0" 
    pr="0" 
    lr="0" 
    color="#FFFFFFFF" 
    desc="Part of an everyday swimming outfit" />
```

Also, theres a lot of more lines in this XML file, so how can I do this with 1 .sql file?

Comment: Are you asking how to deserialize this and insert the structure into a table, or are you asking how to insert this XML blob into an XML datatype column?

Comment: I want to insert this structure into a table, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method which will give you an EAV structure (Entity Attribute Value).

You may notice I only have to identify ONE key element ... id

I truncated a few elements and added a second item for demonstrative purposes only

```
Declare @XML xml = '
<ITEM id="1" name="Swimmer Head" mesh_name="eq_head_swim" totalpoint="0" type="equip" res_sex="m" res_level="0" slot="head" weight="2" bt_price="0" color="#FFFFFFFF" desc="Part of an everyday swimming outfit" />
<ITEM id="2" name="Boxer Feet" mesh_name="eq_feet_boxer" totalpoint="0" type="equip" res_sex="m" res_level="0" slot="head" weight="2" bt_price="25.00" color="#FFFFFFFF" desc="Somthing for the boxer" />
'

Select ID     = r.value('@id','int')
      ,Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/ITEM') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('id')
```

**Returns (which can easily be Pivoted if necessary)**

[image]

> **EDIT - To load XML from a FILE**

```
Declare @XML xml
Select @XML = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Working\SomeXMLFile.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

Select ID     = r.value('@id','int')
      ,Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/ITEM') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('id')
```

Comment: And how can I do it with a 45k lines xml file? If you want, I can upload the XML file so you could check it.

Comment: @J.Litvak See edit to upload a file and process in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Re-asking Siyual's question, but more specific:

Is this one line of many that should go into a table?

And is it not nested?

In other words, would it continue with repetitions of `<ITEM id= [...] desc="something" />` ? If the answer is yes, consider a perl script that picks everything after an equal sign and between double quotes and concatenates the obtained bits, separating them by, say, comma, creating one line per `<ITEM [...] />` .

This way, you'd get a CSV file to load. Of course, you'd have to create the target table first.

Comment: Yes, there are more lines. If you want I can send you the XML file so you would guide me a bit because I'm a complete newbie.